# Java string interpreted wrongly in SQL

Tags: java, sql, string, sql-injection

There is an string[] likely;
This array stores the name of column of database table dynamically while runtime.And the program understand the size of the likely in runtime.
Now to put this in sql query .I use a for loop for concatanation of string

```
for(int k=0;k<likely.length;k++)
    {
        temp1="\"+likely["+k+"]+\"='Likely' AND ";
        temp=temp.concat(temp1);                
    }
```

if the size is 3 the final temp will look like

```
temp = " "+likely[0]+"='Likely' AND "+
    likely[1]+"='Likely' AND "+
    likely[2]+"='Likely' AND "
```

Now i formulate sql query as

```
sql ="SELECT * FROM PUNE WHERE"+temp+"Arts_And_Museum='Yes'";
```

But during the

```
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

this statement is compiled  like

```
SELECT * FROM PUNE 
WHERE [+likely[0]+]='Likely' 
AND [+likely[1]+]='Likely' 
AND [+likely[2]+]='Likely' AND Arts_And_Museum='Yes'
```

After deep investigation ,I came to conclusion that it interprets   \"    as [ or ]  alternately..

As a result i get an error
How should i solve this problem?

I run a for loop and prepare a string 
I am trying to write a sql syntax

Answer (score 1):

This is why you should use parameterized inputs when dealing with SQL queries.

```
// conn refers to your database connection
PreparedStatement stmnt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    stmnt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col > '?'");
    stmnt.setInt(1, 300); //set first parameter to 300
    rs = stmnt.executeQuery();
} catch(Exception ex) {
    System.err.println("Database exception: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: When you parameterize any insert value it will not be parsed as SQL

Answer (score 0):

`\` is a reserved character. If you want to output a quote in your string you use `\"`.

So, this code:

```
temp1="\"+likely["+k+"]+\"='Likely' AND ";
```

Will return this string:

`"+likely`**1**`]+"='Likely' AND`

It seems that your sql is transforming `"` into `[` or `]`

Answer (score 0):

The symbol `\` is used for escaping. On doing this, you are escaping all the front characters.

Whenever you are asking for an item in array you can access it using `likely[k]` no need for `likey["k"]`

Here is how you should do it.

```
temp1="\\"+likely[k]+"\\='Likely' AND ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line:

```
temp1="\"+likely["+k+"]+\"='Likely' AND ";
```

To this one:

```
temp1="\"" + likely[k] + "\"='Likely' AND ";
```

Comment: @ShwetaB.Patil Welcome ^.^ Anyway, there is no need to thanks, that's what accepting answers is there for :)